# Matrix containing integers instead of doubles in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a large vector containing integers (length: 230 400, int8) which I rearrange into a 3-dimensional matrix (rows: 240, cols: 320, depth: 3). When this has been done the new matrix contains doubles instead of ints (according to Matlab Workspace).

The whole operation takes 0.3 seconds, which is to long for my purposes.

Is Matlab converting the ints in the array to doubles before putting them in the matrix?
Can this be avoided to speed it up?

Some code:

```
   tic;
   A=zeros(240,320,3);
   %A is matrix, B is vector.

   for i=1:240
       for j=1:320
           A(i,j,:)=B(1+(j-1)*3+(i-1)*320*3:3+(j-1)*3+(i-1)*320*3);
       end
   end

   toc;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing your matrix with

```
A=zeros(240, 320, 3, 'int8')
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use reshape on B. This is faster and will preserve the class of B.

```
A = reshape(B,[3,320,240]); %# makes a 3-by-320-by-240 array and distributes elements of B
A = permute(A,[3 2 1]);     %# turns A into a 240-by-320-by-3 array
```

Comment: Learn to use reshape, permute and transpose for problems like this, rather than brute force doubly nested loops. This is the art of vectorization, where you learn to operate on arrays with no explicit loops at all.

Comment: I agree with @woodchips. But don't forget that sometimes JIT performs these optimizations for you. Anyhow, it is always a good practice to write a simple code, create a unit test, and only then refactor